# Unable to style the icon in the Alert component in material in react using a separate css file

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I need help understanding how to make my code work. I'm working with MUI styling my components using a separate CSS file. I'm trying to style the following an Alert component and it doesn't work. I want to specifically style the alert icon, however, this style doesn't work.

JSX component:

```
<Alert severity='error' className='passwordAlert'>
    Invalid Password
</Alert>
```

CSS component (this works):

```
.passwordAlert {
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 0%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: center;
}
```

CSS component (this is the part that doesn't work):

```
.passwordAlert.MuiAlert-icon {
    padding-left: 5%;
}
```

I would like to continue using a separate file for style and I know that there are other styling methods, but is there a solution using className and a separate CSS file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining selectors won't work here as MuiAlert-icon and  .passwordAlert don't occur in the same element. Write CSS for  MuiAlert-icon separately.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a global change? I want to only change it for a specific component. Would the only option be to make custom components with styled()?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a separate file and customize MUI components. MUI has many strategies for customizing components. you can read [How to customize MUI components](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just for clarification in the MUI documentation, I believe it says you can use className and a CSS file ([link](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#overriding-styles-with-class-names) and [link](https://mui.com/guides/interoperability/#plain-css)). However, I may be misunderstanding the documentation as I'm still new to Material UI and react.

Comment: For sure most of the components which build in react they have their standard ways of customization you can also style elements by finding their class name so it would not be a standard way of coding.